# How do I calculate the sale price when a % downpayment was made if I have the loan information?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, finance

**The Question**
Anna buys a car by paying 10% down and by financing the balance with a loan at 15%/a, compounded monthly, to amortize the loan by making monthly payments of $225 each month for 3 years. Determine the sale price.

a.  $6490.64

b.  $7932.36

c.  $7211.82

d.  $8821.18

---

Using Present Value formula:
$$PV=R\cdot \frac{1-\left ( 1+i \right )^{-n}}{i}\\
PV=225\cdot \frac{1-\left ( 1+0.0125 \right )^{-36}}{0.0125}\\
PV=225\cdot \frac{1-\left ( 0.639409157 \right )}{0.0125}\\
PV=225\cdot \frac{0.360590842}{0.0125}\\
PV=225\cdot 28.84726737\\
PV=\$ 6490.64$$
However, this does not account for the 10% downpayment.
Calculating 10% of each answer option, allows me to conclude $7211.82 is the answer:

$$$7211.82\cdot 0.10=$721.18\\
\$ 6490.64+$721.18=\$ 7211.82$$
I'm not sure how I would have been able to come to the same conclusion without seeing the answers.

How can I calculate the downpayment with the given information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the sale price. Simply set $6490.64 = x - 0.1x$, or $6490.64 = 0.9x.$ I'm sure you can take it from there.

Comment: I seem to get stuck on small details and can't see the obvious solution. Thank you.